# What is the difference between a USB port and a USB receptacle?

Tags: usb, terminology, port

The Wikipedia article [*USB hardware*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hardware#Standard_connectors) states:

> **Standard connectors**
>
> - The type-A plug. This plug has an elongated rectangular cross-section, inserts into a type-A receptacle on a *downstream port*
>   on a USB host or hub, and carries both power and data. Captive cables
>   on USB devices, such as keyboards or mice, terminate with a type-A
>   plug.
> - The type-B plug: This plug has a near square cross-section with the top exterior corners beveled and inserts into a type-B receptacle on
>   an *upstream port* on a USB device, such as a printer. On some devices,
>   the type-B receptacle has no data connections, being used solely for
>   accepting power from the upstream device. This two-connector-type
>   scheme (A/B) prevents a user from accidentally creating a loop.

Comment: Receptacle is socket, or female connector. Port is the connection point (which could be plug or socket, male or female connector).

Comment: @Puffafish What do you mean by the connection point? Why plug *or* receptacle, isn’t it always plug *and* receptacle (since you cannot connect two plugs or two receptacles)?

Answer (score 9):

The USB 'receptacle' is the mechanical connector - the thing you plug a USB cable into. That consists of electrical contacts in a plastic-and-metal housing.

The USB 'port' describes the connector, communication electronics, software and any power supply electronics needed by the equipment the port is in.

For a PC, the USB port uses a connector, power supply with current control/protection, communications electronics and an OS software driver.

Comment: Thanks TonyM. What do you mean by ‘housing’?

Comment: housing means `enclosure` or `shell`

Comment: Could you provide a reference for these definitions?